# Viewing .gfx file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file

Resonantly I had to work with .gfx file, but i haven't got much information about gfx file.
My question is:

1. What is a .gfx file formated file contains? 
      is that any kind of image file or video file.
2. Where can i get a .gfx sample file to test?
3. is there any framework that support .gfx in iOS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

According to Google, [GFX is used as an extension for at least five different kinds of files](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5489786_file-extension-gfx.html). My first guess is that [you're thinking of a 3D model/scene format](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall01/cps124/code/gfx_reader/docs/gfx_format.html), which might be used in some kinds of games.

2)

That last web page I referred to [lists a sample .gfx file](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall01/cps124/code/gfx_reader/docs/gfx_format.html#sample).

3)

And this answer depends on exactly which kind of file, out of the five different types of files listed on the eHow page, is the kind of file you want to work with.